# Use meta_query to display events by date in custom field

Tags: wp-query, meta-query, date, date-time

I'm working on a template for a specific category archive of the custom post type event.

I need to make a query that shows future and ongoing events, ordering by a date in custom field.

```
$termName = get_queried_object()->name;
$termSlug = get_queried_object()->slug;
$event1 = current_time('Y-m-d');

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'event-categories' => $termSlug,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation'    => 'OR',
        array(
            'relation'    => 'AND',

        array(

            'key' => '_event_start_date',
            'value' => $event1,
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'DATE',

        ),


        array(

            'key' => '_event_end_date',
            'value' => $event1,
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'DATE',

        )
        ),
        array(
            'key' =>  $event1,
            'value' => array('_event_start_date','_event_start_date'),
            'type' => 'DATE',
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
        )

    ),

     'orderby' => '_event_start_date',
 );
$events = new WP_Query($args);
echo $events->post_count   ;
```

The result shows only the future events, but not ongoing events.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Simpler CODE:

Logically, when you check `>=` for both `_event_start_date` and `_event_end_date`, that automatically covers the `BETWEEN` check.

So the following CODE should work:

```
$termName = get_queried_object()->name;
$termSlug = get_queried_object()->slug;
$event1 = current_time( 'Y-m-d' );

$args = array(
    'post_type'        => 'event',
    'event-categories' => $termSlug,
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'   => 10,
    'order'            => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation'    => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => '_event_start_date',
            'value'   => $event1,
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type'    => 'DATE',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => '_event_end_date',
            'value'   => $event1,
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type'    => 'DATE',
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => '_event_start_date',
);
$events = new WP_Query( $args );
echo $events->post_count;
```

### Date check:

Also, make sure the date value `$event1` is properly set as the one stored in Database (in post meta table). Normally, WordPress internally considers all `date` to be in the `GMT` timezone. However, that may vary depending on how the `_event_start_date` and `_event_end_date` is saved in your case. It can be different depending on the stored value:

```
// MySQL DATETIME field format
$event1 = current_time( 'mysql' );

// MySQL DATETIME field format in GMT
$event1 = current_time( 'mysql', 1 );

// Unix timestamp in local time zone
$event1 = current_time( 'timestamp' );

// Unix timestamp in GMT
$event1 = current_time( 'timestamp', 1 );
```

So, better check how that data is saved, or test with these variances. If `date` fields include time as well, then you may also work with `DATETIME` type.

Also, a note from [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query):

> The 'type' DATE works with the 'compare' value BETWEEN only if the date is stored at the format `YYYY-MM-DD` and tested with this format.

### `tax` Query :

The old `tax` query is deprecated. So instead of using:

```
'event-categories' => $termSlug,
```

use:

```
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'event-categories',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $termSlug,
    ),
),
```